# Is there a way to add different arrays where some elements from one array are used repeatedly?

Tags: python, arrays, data-manipulation

I'm new to python and I'm trying to find the best way to transform my array.
I have two arrays,  A and B. I want to add them together such that every value of array A is added to two values of array B

```
A = np.array(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
B = np.array(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
```

combining the two would give me array C as

```
C = np.array(12, 12, 14, 14, 16, 16, 18, 18, 20, 20)
```

I though maybe a for loop might achieve this, but I'm not sure how to specify to apply each value of array A twice before continuing. Any help would be appreciated thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), add and reshape back:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
B = np.array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])

res = (B.reshape((-1, 2)) + A[:, None]).reshape(-1)

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[12 12 14 14 16 16 18 18 20 20]
```

The expression:

```
B.reshape((-1, 2))
```

creates the following array:

```
[[10 10]
 [10 10]
 [10 10]
 [10 10]
 [10 10]]
```

basically you tell numpy fit the array in a 2 by *N*, column where *N* is determined by the original size of `B` (this is all due to the -1). The other part:

```
A[:, None]
```

creates:

```
[[ 2]
 [ 4]
 [ 6]
 [ 8]
 [10]]
```

Then using [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting) you can add them together. Finally reshape back.

Answer (score 0):

It's sort of hacky and not quite for a beginner:

```
(A[None, :] + B.reshape((2, -1))).reshape(-1)
```

`A[None, :]` treats A as a 1x5 array.  `B.reshape((2, -1))` treats B as a 2x5 array.  Python knows how to add 1x5 arrays to 2x5 arrays via broadcasting.  The final reshape turns the 2x5 array back into a 10-element array.

-1 in a reshape says "make this dimension as large as necessary to use all the data."  That way, I don't have to bake 2x5 into the code, but this will work for any n-element and 2-n element arrays.

Comment: Heh. Two of us posted nearly the identical answer at the same time!  With nearly the same explanation!

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this out, so helpful as my array, in reality, is 100k-n elements long... thank you again!

Comment: oops, I meant 2-100k elements. slightly elated that my question even got any answers let alone such helpful ones!

Comment: The solutions above should work for any size arrays.  The .reshape() doesn't copy the underlying data; it creates a new header that points to the already existing data but interprets it as a different size array.  Likewise, if each element of A applies to 10 elements of B, just change the `2` above to `10`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use slicing to index every other item from A then augmented addition for in-place transformation. I don't know the details of how numpy will handle the slicing, but I think this will use the least memory.

```
B[::2] += A
B[1::2] += A
```

Another way to expand and reshape is

```
B += np.array([A, A]).flatten("F")
```

It loooks to me that this will use 4x the size of A but I think all of the reshaping methods will eat memory.